# Getting properties from Appointments not exposed in the API

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, office365-apps

Is it possible to retrieve properties not exposed by the office.js API for appointment items in the OWA in a HTML Add-In (e.g. Milage) hosted on an Exchange 2013 Server (otherwise I could use EWS from the offíce js, i think in ex2016) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. We are not able to get the properties which not exposed by the Office API. But we can use EWS from the mail app directly by **makeEwsRequestAsync**.

And we can use **GetItem** operation to get the specified properties and contents of items from the Exchange store.

[Here](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/web-services) is the document reference for Call web services from an Outlook add-in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that was what i feared. Unfortunately saveAsync (which would be needed to get an ItemID if the item was just created) is not part of the 1.1 requirement set, so the only way to get/set the properties not exposed seems to be targeting ex2016 and higher